# Google Search API for desktop application. Which API to use to make maximum requests per day?

Tags: api, search, google-search, google-search-api

I'm building an application that should query Google search very often. But i'm having trouble choosing which API i should use. There are so many of them - AJAX, REST, Web, SOAP, Custom and maybe something else. Some of them are deprecated now. From that list, from what i understand, only AJAX and Custom Search API are not. Custom Search API has 100 requests per day limit. Very small amount. I couldn't find any published limits for AJAX API, but it looks like i can do only 20 requests per hour or so. Also not so good.

So, which API should i use in desktop application to get as much as possible? And second question: what else i can do to increase the limit? Maybe set appropriate http headers, use API key or something else?